# Hexadecimal Number corresponding to 4 Bit

Tags: binary, numbers, hex

I am wondering why a hexadecimal number corresponds to 4 Bits of memory. 
My thinking is that:

HEX = 16 digits --> So you need 16 possible combinations therefore 4 bits as they offer you 16 possible combinations --> 2^4

BInary = 2 digits --> 2 possible combinations so 1 bit is enough as 1 bit offers 2 possible combinations

Decimal --> Decimal would then require 5 bits, correct? As you need 10 possible combinations, therefore 5 bits.

Please verify if my thinking is correct, especially with the HEX and Decimal.

Thanks

Comment: You're right, except that decimal requires only about 3.3 bits (3 bits would give you 0..7, 4 bits gives you 0..15, so for 0..9 you need somewhere between 3 and 4 bits). The exact value is log2(10) = 3.32192809488736 bits.

Comment: Yes; somehow your reasoning for Decimal is entirely off.

Comment: 16 combinations require 4 bits, so 10 combinations clearly require 5 bits...!? ;-P

Comment: thanks, @Jongware: yes I somehow twisted it.. I just wrote down the decimal numbers up to ten in binary and recognized my mistake..

Comment: @deceze: jajaja I see how dumb it was :)

Comment: i sometimes get it twisted ;P

Comment: By the way, your reasoning for using *hexadecimal* is also the wrong way around. Since 4 bits (and multiples of that) cannot be expressed nicely in decimal, we use hexadecimal notation for convenience. It's not as if "first" there was hex and then computers were designed around that.